# Get ids where all values of a field have a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
f_id  |  user_id | sent
==============================
  1   |   1      | 0
  1   |   2      | 1397820533
  1   |   3      | 0
  1   |   4      | 1397820533
  2   |   1      | 1397820533
  2   |   2      | 1397820533
  2   |   3      | 1397820533
  3   |   1      | 1397820533
  3   |   2      | 1397820533
```

now I would like to have all `f_id`'s where **all** `sent` fields have a timestamp ( != 0 )

```
SELECT * FROM  table WHERE sent != 0 GROUP BY f_id
```

returns all three cause there are some which have a timestamp.

A a result I expect

```
f_id
=====
  2
  3
```

cause `f_id` still have some 0 values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but you want to move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT f_id
FROM  table 
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING SUM(sent = 0) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows with `sent = 0`.  The `= 0` means there are none of them.

Comment: just out of curiousity,what kind of t.s is `1397820533` ??

Comment: @NoobEditor . . . It looks like a Unix date format, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  If so, it corresponds to 2014-04-18 11:28:53.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct f_id 
  FROM  table 
   WHERE sent >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM  table 
     WHERE sent != 0) tempalias 
GROUP BY f_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
     SELECT * FROM  table 
     WHERE f_id not in (select f_id from table where sent=0)
     GROUP BY f_id